# Create a Table of Contents / Linked list of all terms within a glossary in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, glossary

I am using the Glossary directive in Sphinx and would like to have a list of all terms include in the glossary, linked to the terms. Is there a simple way to do this automatically?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want to take a term `MyTerm` and automatically insert the `:term:` directive and wrap `MyTerm` with backticks. When rendered it will create a link from `MyTerm` to its definition in your glossary. There is nothing that does that automatically, and you would have to write your own script and regex.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you want "a list of all terms include in the glossary"? The glossary already is a list of terms, isn't it?

Comment: @mzjn: I only wanted the list of all terms, linked to its respective definition. So like a table of contents of the complete glossary.

Comment: @StevePiercy: yes, I guess that is what I wanted and since I also did not find a way, one would need to write a script for that. When creating a PDF via latex, it is actually created at the end as an "Index", that is actually just what I was looking for, just to be used in `make html`. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: An alphabetical index is generated also for HTML output. Glossary terms are added to this index automatically.

Comment: @mzjn: Thanks for the reply. I now found it, I just did not see the "index" link at the top right!  Just what I was searching.